# "IndexError: string index out of range" if user input is any control keys from the keyboard

Tags: python

```
def repeat_game():
    user_input = str(raw_input("\nWanna Play again??? \nTo play type 'YES|yes|Yes|Y|y' or 'Any key' to exit : "))
    if user_input[0]== 'Y' or user_input[0] == 'y':
        quiz(diff_level(),no_of_attempts())
    else:
        sys.exit("Thank You!")
```

My code gives "IndexError: string index out of range" error if the user inputs control keys in the keyboard... How do I make the function exit without raising an error..

Comment: don't assume the string has a 1st element (that is, non-empty).

Comment: It's like a zen riddle: what is the first character of a string with no characters?

Comment: Just change your test to `if user_input and user_input[0].upper() == 'Y':`

Comment: the if condition is working fine.. the error is due to the else condition.. if i input anything other than alphabets and letters, its throwing Index Error. how do i change it so that it exits the function for any input?

Comment: The `if` statement is the only line of the given code that could generate an IndexError (directly). The error is telling you that there is no character 0 in `user_input`. In other words, it's empty. You're not accounting for that, which is a problem regardless of any concerns about control characters.

Comment: thank u @glibdud .. Used IndexError exception to handle the error.. thanks a lot. :-)